# redirection of a custom port website from http to https

Tags: http, redirect, https, port

i have configured a website on IIS6 using openssl certificate with custom port 86 and it is working fine, this website was running with simple http on port 86 before, hence users have bookmark this website. Now i want redirect http (port 86) requests to https (port 86), is it possible?